# Wait for foreach to complete NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So, I am creating an API in NodeJS. In one API, I have to call for loop within mongoose query.

How do I wait for the forEach to complete before executing res.send()? I have attached my code below.

```
router.post("/getResult", function (req, res) {
    const lottery_id = req.body.lottery_id;
    const prizeQuery = Prize.find({"lotid": lottery_id});

    let response = [];

    prizeQuery.exec(function (err, prizes) {
        console.log(prizes.length);
        if (err) return res.send({success: 0, data: err});
        else {
            prizes.forEach(prize => {
                let prizeData = {};
                const winnerQuery = Winner.find({"id": prize._id});
                winnerQuery.exec(function (err, winners) {
                    if (err) return res.send({success: 0, data: err});
                    else {
                        prizeData = {
                            prize: prize,
                            winners: winners
                        };
                        response.push(prizeData);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
    return res.send({success:1, data: response});
});
```

In the code above, return is called before forEach is completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are running asynchronous code inside the `forEach` and `forEach` will not wait until the asynchronous code finish, to do so, you must wrap your async code with a waiting primitive.

Also the code you provided will call `send` twice in case of failure, because the return inside the `forEach` will not actually end the enclosing function.

```
try {
    await Promise.all(prizes.map(async (prize) => {
        const winners = await Winner.find({"id": prize._id});
        response.push({prize, winners});
    }))
    res.send({success:1, data: response});
} catch (err) {
    res.send({success: 0, data: err});
}
```

Comment: it says await can only be used in async function. I guess I will create a new function or is there any way to make router.post() async?

Comment: yes just add `async function (req, res) {` instead of `function (req, res) {`

Comment: I've updated the code also no need to call `exec` ;)

Comment: Yes I realized that. Code is much cleaner this way\

Comment: Thanks very much, was testing and trying to figure this thing out for hours.

Answer (score 0):

@Rami's answer is correct but addition to that you can also use `forof` for your code to work. `forof` works synchronously so there will be no need for promise. like

```
          for (let prize of prizes){
                let prizeData = {};
                try{
                  const winnerQuery = Winner.find({"id": prize._id});
                  const winners = await winnerQuery.exec()
                  prizeData = {
                              prize: prize,
                              winners: winners
                          };
                  response.push(prizeData);   
                }catch(err){
                 console.error(err)
                }
            }
```